# Is there any workaround to support pattern replace filter for numeric fields in SOLR 5?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

For instance I have a `solr.TrieFloatField` field which contains some ASCII symbol, that hampers the proper indexation process. I want to eliminate this symbol without changing field type to `solr.TextField`.

What is the workaround in Lucene/Solr for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UpdateRequestProcessor chains to modify the value before it gets indexed. The [full list of available URPs for Sorl 5.5](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/archive/urp_5_5_0.html) is available on solr-start. One that seems relevant is RegexReplaceProcessorFactory.